# Error with matplotlib on Ubuntu Server and SSH

Tags: python, matplotlib, ssh

I am working on a weather station project with the Arduino and I need to run a python program ([click here](https://github.com/Alex1942/WeCMS/blob/master/WeCMS_plotter/plot_norm.py)) I developed on a computer that runs Ubuntu Server. I connect to the computer though SSH. The SSH client is a Windows 7 laptop and the software I am using is called PuTTY.

When I run the python program I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plot_norm.py", line 9, in <module>
    fig1 = plt.figure(1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 535, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 81, in new_figure_manager
    return new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, figure)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 89, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
    window = Tk.Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1818, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

How can I fix the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not need interactive backend, you need to do this in your import statements. The order is very important. First matplotlib, then matplotlib.use and finally import pyplot.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

This changes the backend to a non-interactive one. If you do need an interactive backend, then ignore this and use `ssh -X` when logging into the remote host. It allows X11 forwarding.

Comment: It worked (i used the matplotlib.use('Agg')), but now my code seems to ignore the anf1 = anim.FuncAnimation(fig1, animatef1, interval=45000) and anf2 = anim.FuncAnimation(fig2, animatef2, interval=45000) lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Γεια σου Alex, Athan here.
You should post a minimal working example of your code first. Then elaborate on

> my code seems to ignore...